# Excel Evaluate Function Returns #REF When Using Indirect

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lookup which returns a formula as text, depending on the value of a particular cell.

The formula (as text) returned looks like this:

```
SUM(INDIRECT("AF"&row()),INDIRECT("AG"&row()))
```

I then use the `EVALUATE()` function to evaluate the formula, but receive a #REF error because of the use of `INDIRECT()`.

[This Microsoft Support Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131384) was the only reference that I could find to this particular problem, and it doesn't seem to offer an appropriate workaround.

How can I either: a) restructure the formula to avoid using `INDIRECT`, or b) get `EVALUATE()` to play nice?

**EDIT**

The lookup table looks something like this:

Type A                    SUM(INDIRECT("AF"&row()),INDIRECT("AG"&row()))
Type B                    SUM(INDIRECT("AF"&row()),INDIRECT("AG"&row()), INDIRECT("AH"&Row()))

On another sheet, the contents of cells B1:200 are either Type A or Type B. A lookup returns the formula string based on the value of the cell and puts it into Bx. I then Evaluate the string to give me the result.

Comment: You're using evaluate() as part of an XLM macro, or in a worksheet cell?

Comment: I'm actually using it in a named range, which I then call from a cell.

Comment: Can you show the lookup?  It's not clear what the context for row() is.  I'm not sure you need both indirect and evaluate, since they both serve a similar purpose...

Comment: Possibly it's that `ROW` returns an *array* based on it's argument? That is, `ROW()` returns a one-element array with the currently selected row number. `ROW(a42:q99)` returns {42; 43; ...; 99}, etc. Just a comment since I don't have Excel handy to mess with this...

Comment: @Tim, please see my edit with the lookup table. INDIRECT doesn't evaluate a formula, only interprets text as a cell reference. That's why I need both.

Comment: Using a defined name with a refersto of =EVALUATE(SUM(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))) works OK for me: can you give us a specific example which fails.

Comment: @Charles, sure. Place the text "typeA" in cell C1. Place the values 1 and 2 in cells A1 and B1 respectively. Add a new named range called "typeA" with the formula you suggested. Now, in cell D1 place the formula =INDIRECT(C1). You will receive a #REF error. Now imagine if I have several named ranges with names like "typeB", "typeC", etc., each with different SUM formulas. I want to be able to display the SUM in cell D1 depending on the value you type in C1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK 3rd attempt at an answer:

thanks for the example: it fails because you are trying to use INDIRECT to evaluate a named formula and INDIRECT only handles references not formulas.

You need to use EVALUATE instead, but there is no built-in EVALUATE worksheet function (the EVALUATE you are using in the defined name is an ancient XLM Macro function).
I suggest you use my EVAL VBA UDF instead

```
Public Function EVAL(theInput As Variant) As Variant
'
' if UDF evaluate the input string as though it was on this sheet
' else evaluate for activesheet
'
Dim vEval As Variant
Application.Volatile
On Error GoTo funcfail
If not IsEmpty(theInput) then
If TypeOf Application.Caller.Parent Is Worksheet Then
vEval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(Cstr(theInput))
Else
vEval = Application.Evaluate(cstr(theInput))
End If
If IsError(vEval) Then
EVAL = CVErr(xlErrValue)
Else
EVAL = vEval
End If
End If
Exit Function
funcfail:
EVAL = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

and then use defined names with relative references like typeA=SUM(Sheet3!RC1,Sheet3RC2).

There are some "quirks" of EVALUATE that you should be aware of: see
http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm

Comment: This seems to be the closest result to what I was trying to get to. Thanks so much for your help and your patience.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, why not get the resukt directly from the cell .. 
I don't think you need indirect because you just need the text of the formula 
(altho I am not sure what the ROW() is supposed to be doing)
SUM("AF"&row(),"AG"&row())

Comment: Charles, row() gets a reference to the current row. Unfortunately building the SUM like that won't work, because it needs the INDIRECT to interpret your text as a cell. It's the difference between =SUM("AF2","AG2") which doesn't work, and =SUM(AF2,AG2) which does.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a Defined Name to add column AF and AG on the current row then just use relative references (easier to define in R1C1 mode, then switch back to A1)
Defined Name AndySum has Refersto formula of `=SUM(RC32,RC33)`
 Then wherever you use AndySum in a formula it will add the contents of columns AF and AG on that row.

Comment: Understood, but it's not always AF and AG that will need to be added. I have edited the question as requested by Tim, but it might help explain better what it is I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: So why not use the Lookup formula with an IF or CHOOSE to choose between  various flavours of Defined Names

Comment: Because I might have a couple of hundred Types in my lookup table, which would lead to a couple of hundred defined names, and a super long IF formula...

Answer (score 0):

To extend Charles' answer: this function will take care of the lookup and evaluate the row number.  I'm assuming the formula (in your examples) is just intended to sum certain values from the same row as the cell returning the end result.

My lookup table looks like this:

```
TypeA   SUM(B<r> ,D<r>) 
TypeB   SUM(C<r>,D<r>)
```

UDF:

```
Public Function GetAndRunCalc(CalcType As String)
Application.Volatile
    Dim ac As Object, rw, f

    On Error GoTo haveError

    If TypeOf Application.Caller.Parent Is Worksheet Then
        Set ac = Application.Caller
        rw = ac.Parent.Range(ac.Address).Row
        'adjust for your lookup table...
        f = Application.VLookup(CalcType, Sheet1.Range("B4:C5"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(f) Then
            f = Replace(f, "<r>", rw)
            GetAndRunCalc = ac.Parent.Evaluate(f)
        Else
            GetAndRunCalc = "Type??"
        End If
    Else
        GetAndRunCalc = "Must be called from worksheet cell"
    End If

    Exit Function

haveError:
    GetAndRunCalc = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

*waking up a sleeping thread*

This question pertains to the use of INDIRECT inside either the "EXCEL 4.0 MACRO" EVALUATE() named range to evaluate a text string as a formula (as if it were entered into a cell). It also applies to the VBA Application.Evaluate() function which can be called from within a VBA UDF and then used in a cell. (The two methods are similar, though with the UDF it is easier to pass the string as an argument, whereas with the named range you have to use relative named ranges to pass the string from say an adjacent cell or use the new Office 365 LAMBDA function. Both methods require saving as a macro enabled workbook, so it horses for courses.) Regardless which one you use, I will refer to it simply as EVAL(*string*).

The issue when using INDIRECT inside an EVAL function is it returns #REF or #VALUE errors. The cause of this in many cases seems to be the use of an apostrophe (") in the text formula, as EVAL automatically inserts apostrophes into the string. Have a look what happens when you try to step through the formula using "Show calculation steps" from the cell error pop-up menu. Now, in most cases you do not actually have to use the indirect function as EVAL is already indirect (as @Charles Williams said). It acts on text, not references.

In other words you can build a string in say in A1 `="SUM(AF"&ROW()&":AG"&ROW()&")"` and then call `=EVAL(A1)` without any problems.

**TLDR Don't put any apostrophe's in the text that is fed to either Application.Evaluate (VBA) or the Excel 4.0 EVALUATE named range.**